# javascript: undefined variable

Tags: javascript, undefined

my variable 'todoList' is showing up as undefined. i am very new to javascript and programming in general. any help would greatly be appreciated!

```js
var todoList = {
  todos:[],
  displayTodos: function() {
    if (this.todos.length === 0) {
      console.log ('Your todos list is empty!');
    } else {
      console.log('My Todos:');
      for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
        if (this.todos[i].completed === true) {
          console.log ('(x)', this.todos[i].todoText);
        } else {
          console.log('( )', this.todos[i].todoText);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  addTodo: function(todoText) {
    this.todos.push({
      todoText: todoText,
      completed: false
    });
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  changeTodo: function(position, todoText) {
    this.todos[position].todoText = todoText;
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  deleteTodo: function(position) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleCompleted: function(position) {
    var todo = this.todos[position];
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleAll: function() {
    var totalTodos = this.todos.length;
    var completedTodos = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
      if(this.todos[i].completed === true) {
        completedTodos++;
      }
    }
    if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
      for(var i =0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
        this.todos[i].completed === false;
      }
    }
    this.displayTodos;
  }
};
```

Comment: Your code for declaring and assigning `todoList` looks fine.  You'll need to provide more details on where in your code the variable is `undefined`.

Comment: try to add `&& !this.todos[i].todoText` on your `if (this.todos[i].completed === true)`

Comment: Maybe you are trying to access to the todoList object from higher scope, so the todoList is not visible, hereby is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript always returns *something*. If I copy/paste your code into the Chrome console and run it, it tells me the returned result of running that code is *undefined*. That's okay, since you're just setting up the object and have no intention of using the return value.

[image]

After this, the object has been created and typing it into the Chrome console tells us that the variable `todoList` is an object.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful!

Comment: Glad it was helpful, @justinsunghokim. If you're satisfied with my answer, can you accept it?